# margin shown in different way with chrome and correct with firefox

Tags: html, css

Margin not display in correct way  , I have no idea why ? 
I noted 4px more in chrome in box_news element , I road something about rest.css but I didn't sure if it will be useful in my status .

this code of right side :

```
<div class="rightside">


 ﻿﻿ <div class="box_news">
                            <h1>الاخبار</h1>

                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="centerIt">
            <div class="readmore"><a href="#">مزيد من الاخبار</a></div>
            </div>
               <br><br>
    </div>




﻿﻿
<div class="box1">
<h1>آخر معارض الصور</h1>

﻿
    <table align="center">
<tbody><tr>
    <td align="center"><img width="140" height="110" src="./Chrome_files/illaf693012853.jpg" alt="alt">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    <a class="gallery" href="http://domain.com/ictproject/site/gallery?gal_id=13">اللاذقية 2013: مساعد ممارس في البرمجة اللغوية العصبية</a><br>2013-03-03</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
    <table align="center">
<tbody><tr>
    <td align="center"><img width="140" height="110" src="./Chrome_files/illaf654896994.jpg" alt="alt">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    <a class="gallery" href="http://domain.com/ictproject/site/gallery?gal_id=5">دورة المغرب الصور الكاملة </a><br>0000-00-00</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
    <table align="center">
<tbody><tr>
    <td align="center"><img width="140" height="110" src="./Chrome_files/illaf906907216.jpg" alt="alt">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    <a class="gallery" href="http://domain.com/ictproject/site/gallery?gal_id=12">اللاذقية 2012: دبلوم البرمجة اللغوية العصبية (2)</a><br>0000-00-00</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <div class="centerIt">
         <div class="readmore"><a href="http://domain.com/ictproject/site/Galleries">مزيد من المعارض</a></div>
         </div>
</div>﻿﻿



        </div>
```

css :

```
.rightside {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 215px;
}

.box1{
display: block;
position: relative;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #cccccc;
color:#666666;
font-family: DroidKufi-Regular;
font-size:12px;

width: 98%;
margin-top: -27px;


}

.box1 p {font-size:12px; text-align: right; color:#666666;}
.box1 a { text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px gray; color:#1570a6; }
.box1 a:hover { color:#49a4da; }
.box1 H1{
color:#1570a6;
font-family: DroidKufi-Regular;
font-size:14px;
border-bottom:thin #eee solid;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
padding:5px;
}
.box_news{
 margin-top: -27px;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #cccccc;
color:#666666;
font-family: DroidKufi-Regular;
font-size:12px;

width: 98%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 100%;

}
.box_news H1{

color:#8b9801;
font-family: DroidKufi-Regular;
font-size:14px;
border-bottom:thin #eee solid;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
padding:5px;

}
.news_title{
color:#8b9801;
font-family: DroidKufi-Regular;
font-size:11px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
padding:0px;    
}
.news_title a{
color:#8b9801;
}
.news_title a:hover{
color:#;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #EEE;
}
.news_time{
color:#cccccc;
font-family: DroidKufi-Regular;
font-size:10px;
border-bottom:thin #eee solid;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px gray;
padding:0 10 0 0px; 
}
.readmore{
    display:block;
    width:110px;
    height:24px;
    font-size:12px;
    background:url(../images/readmore.png) no-repeat center;
    font-family:DroidKufi-Regular;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:4 0 0 5px;
    margin:4px;
}
.readmore a{color:#FFF;}
.readmore a:hover{text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0a4e76;}
```

Firefox
[image: Wrok]

Chrome
[image: problem]

Any help will be so useful for me thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding:5px;` from `.box_news H1` it will work

Comment: The problem not fixed so i added new css file for Chrome and then I fixed it .
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== false)
{
    $urls=Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
    // User agent is Google Chrome
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  href='$urls/css/chtt.css' />";
}

Comment: @ahmad if u were able to fix the problem,thats what we needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Now define `overflow:hidden`  on **your** `.box_news`

**as like this**

```
.box_news{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a variation in the font in both the browsers..
the font looks quite bigger and stretched in chrome..

Comment: But I removed font and  H1 but not worked , still have problem

Comment: Ankur may be on the right track though. Maybe you could try a normalization stylesheet? It helps to make browsers CSS behave in a similar way. http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/